# Is there a way to get readable iOS crash logs for crashes within a binary framework (cocoapod)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, crashlytics

I have a binary framework (cocoapod) created using `vendored_frameworks` in the podspec. The code for this framework is not exposed (it shows up as XYZ.framework in Pods when installed in an app).

When the app crashes due to a line within the framework, Crashlytics of the app shows **hidden** in the stack trace: `0x101c62340 _hidden#362_ + 95 (__hidden#402_:95)`

#### What I have tried:

I have tried uploading the dSYM generated while building the framework to the Crashlytics of the app to desymbolicate the crashes, however, it still shows up as hidden.

[image]

Comment: I personally think it's a great question. Advanced debugging techniques are always useful and fascinating to me, but I wonder if StackOverflow really the best one of the StackExchange sites to post this question? There is the ["Ask Different"](https://apple.stackexchange.com) site, which self-describes as "Q&A for power users of Apple Hardware and Software" you might want to try if you don't get your answer here.  Has Googling` Cocoapods dsym debugging` been unhelpful?

Comment: @clearlight Thank you for the suggestion about "Ask different" I did not really know about it. I will definitely post my question there. I did not find any solution by googling "cocoapods dsym debugging" ... have been stuck on this for a couple of weeks now.

Comment: Do you see any missing dSYM UUIDs under your missing dSYM files?